# Solvable group with a composition series is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Prove that a solvable group with a composition series is finite.

A subnormal series $G = G_0 > G_1 > · · · > G_n $is a composition
series if each factor $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is simple. Also , the group is solvable which means that there exists an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $G^{(n)} =e$, and there is a result such that  a group is solvable iff it has a solvable series, which means $G_i /G_{i+1}$ is abelian.

Let it be infinite on the contrary which means that each $G_i /G_{i+1}$ is simple for all i which means that there exists no proper normal subgroup and also it is abelian.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$1 = G_0 \triangleleft G_1 \triangleleft \dots \triangleleft G_{n-1} \triangleleft G_n = G$$
be a composition series of $G$. Since $G$ is solvable this series has to be solvable (this is a consequence of Jordan–Hölder theorem). This means that for every $i=1,2,\dots,n$ we have $G_i/G_{i-1}$ simple and abelian. Now try to prove that the only such groups are the finite cyclic ones. When you prove this the result follows immediately by Lagrange.

Comment: "Since G is solvable this series has to be solvable (this is a consequence of Jordan–Hölder theorem)" It can be proved without using Jordan-Holder Theorem.  We have $G_i/G_{i−1 }$ simple and abelian can you please explain how should I prove that only such groups are finite cyclic ones? Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @Avenger If a group is simple and abelian then it is generated by every non zero element, therefore it has to be cyclic (if $0 \neq x \in G$ then $\langle x \rangle \triangleleft G$)

Comment: If group G is simple then only normal subgroups are {e} and G and if it is abelian then every subgroup is normal. But how did you proved that it will be generated by every non-zero element?